# Precisely which rules disallow spinning sets and open-hand passes?

Tags: rules, beach-volleyball

I've looked at FIVB indoor volleyball rules and FIVB beach volleyball rules.

I can't figure out which rules sections numbers lead to someone calling fault when:

1. a hand-set has too much rotation
2. a serve is received with an open-hand pass

I want to emphasize my *only* interest is to learn which FIVB or AVP rules section numbers apply, directly or indirectly, to the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular rule for this; both those faults would just be considered as either a double touch

> 9.1.1 A player may not hit the ball two times consecutively

or a catch

> 9.2.2 The ball must not be caught or thrown

Those quotes from *either* the [FIVB Beach Volleyball Rules 2015-2016](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/RulesOfTheGame_BVB.asp) or the [FIVB Indoor Rules 2015-2016](http://www.fivb.org/EN/Refereeing-Rules/RulesOfTheGame_VB.asp); the wording and numbering is identical between the two rule books. The difference between the two rule sets comes in how strictly the rules are interpreted with the beach interpretations generally being much stricter.

Comment: The ref I asked yesterday said she considers these covered by 9.3.3, 9.3.4.  Your answer sounds valid too. I'm convinced this is an interpretation issue and is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this and thought I'd give you an answer...
Neither of the things you listed are faults for FIVB USAV indoor (AVP Beach may be different).  If a ref calls either of those for that reason "too much rotation" or "you set the first ball," It's a bad ref who doesn't know the rules.
The fault is in the contact.  If the ref can't describe what it was about the contact  that s/he didn't like (or describes something that happened after the contact e.g. spin), they made a poor call.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE! Can you provide supporting resources to your answer?